The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request？
When I use the following code, the application always throws an error, as shown below:
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application reques.
And this exception occurs randomly.
private async void btnConnectSerial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bllControlCard.OpenSerial();//open serialport
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            try
            {
                await ReceiveDataAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            }
        }
private async Task ReceiveDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    while (bllControlCard.byteToRead())
                    {
                        //Get data from the serial port.
                        //The Read method of SerialPort throws an error.
                    }
                }
            },cancellationToken,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
private  void btnDisConnectSerial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bllControlCard.CloseSerial();//close serialport
            cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        }

How can I resolve this issue?
